# Allow a specific file type to be rendered in iFrame

Tags: security, central-administration, configuration

We've been looking at enabling the Permissive File Handling in Central Admin of our SharePoint 2010 on an intranet site collection. However, we're wondering if we can allow specific file types to be rendered: In our case, we need users to be able to upload and display *.HTML files in the iframe web part. Is this possible or is it all-or-nothing?

Unless we set it to Permissive, SharePoint offers to let us download the HTML file rather than rendering it in the iframe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrote a blog on this some time back:

http://vrdmn.blogspot.in/2012/06/use-html-pages-in-sharepoint-2010-html.html

> So basically there are two modes for file handling in SharePoint 2010.
>   "Strict" and "Permissive". Strict mode entails that only the trusted
>   filetypes in the web application are opened in the browser. For all
>   the rest of the filetypes the response will include a
>   "X-Download-Options: noopen" header. This header will basically
>   instruct the browser not to open the file inline. When the mode is
>   Permissive, no such restriction will be placed on the files. If a file
>   lives inside SharePoint, then it will be displayed inline by the
>   browser.
>
> You can create a hybrid approach by keeping the Browser file handling
>   mode as "Strict" and using the
>   SPWebApplication.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes property of the web
>   application to specify which file types are trusted in your web
>   application.

Comment: Please try to provide a little summary, backed with link to your blog.

Comment: It's an interesting trick to use the *.aspx on the *.html file; it fools SharePoint into rendering the page without using Permissive file handling.

Comment: @ AlexC Glad I could help
@FalakMahmood No problem. Updated the comment.

Comment: Great @VardhamanDeshpande

Answer (score 2):

Use [AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.allowedinlinedownloadedmimetypes.aspx)

Here is code for a single web app in PowerShell

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://intranet.contoso.com
$webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add("text/html")
$webApp.Update()
```

Or for all in C#

```
SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
SPWebService service = farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>("");

foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in service.WebApplications)
{
    webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add("text/html")
    webApp.Update()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Per Jakobsen. Is it possible to do this in server-side code rather than PowerShell?

Comment: Yes. I've added code for enabling it on all WebApps using c# in answer. But often you'll put it in a feature receiver of a WebApp scoped feature in that case you get the webApp from the Parent property